# Ionic 2 InAppBrowser options not working

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic2

The inAppBrowser works and it opens a URL but I want it to be more seamless in the experience. Almost to the point where it doesn't feel like you've actually left the app. Whenever I try passing any options it doesn't seem to take. In the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) it seems straight forward, you just pass a long string seperated by commas but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried:

```
  const browser = this.iab.create('http://example.net','_self', "location=no,toolbar=no,closebuttoncaption=home,transitionstyle=fliphorizontal");
```

even:

```
 const browser = this.iab.create('http://example.net','_self', "location='no',toolbar='no',closebuttoncaption='home',transitionstyle='fliphorizontal'");
```

None of these options seem to take. on iOS it always seems to open up the URL in a safari web view with the toolbar at the bottom and the url/location bar at the top...

Anyone else experiencing this? I should mention this behavior is for iOS

Comment: Does this work with only one parameter? (ie - Does, `const browser = this.iab.create('http://example.net','_self', "location=no"` work?)

Comment: @nipuna777 nope the address bar is still at the top :( I've tried doing single like location=no or toolbar=no and it doesn't do anything

Comment: What versions of Ionic and iab are you using? Also, does this affect only iOS(And what version?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  `'_blank'` instead of `'_self'` as target.

**OR**

Add this to your config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```